# Why am I getting a table doesn't exist error for a table that exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a simple update statement:

```
UPDATE sometab
SET `somefield1` = '19',
    `somefield2` = '3734941'
WHERE somefield3 = '1234';
```

and I am getting the error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'prod._sometab_new' doesn't exist
```

I can successfully select from the table where somefield3 is 1234.
Why am I getting a table doesn't exist error for a table that exists?  And why does the error message refer to a different table?  I don't see any triggers associated with the table.

Additional information: A colleague just noticed that it is referring to a prod scheme, but the statement is running in a dev schema built from prod.  The update statement works in DBs that were built a few days ago using the same method, but all of the DBs built after some, as of yet, unknown time exhibit the error.

Comment: Is there an stored procedure/trigger running?

Comment: Because the table doesn't exist in `prod`.  I note that your query has the table `sometab` but the error is on `_sometab_new`.

Comment: @Jens There are no triggers and this is in the `mysql` tool.  It is also happening in some Perl code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Right, the big question is why it cares about prod._sometab_new when the statement is for sometab.

Comment: Is there onUpdate event for some of the fields you use?

Comment: This is a typical situation, when you try to access a table that exists, but you don't have rights to access it. Check if you are connected as right user and check if the user you are connected as has the rights for the operation you try to do.

Comment: assure that a user do you use have the necessery previlege to doing an update.

Comment: @bksi Could you expand on that?  I know nothing about onUpdate events.  In my day we called things like that triggers and show triggers says there are none on this DB.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html You can use this event to update field to current timestamp

Comment: Did you manually move database files?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt not to my knowledge.  My understanding of the process is that the schema is created and then table contents are dumped out of the readonly prod db and loaded into the dev instances.

Comment: @bksi A `show create table sometab` shows that we use constant defaults on the columns that have defaults at all.

Comment: @BenTayaa `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` shows that I have update on `dev\_%` and my current scheme is `dev_cowens`.  But this points back to the big question: why is it referring to a different schema (prod) in the error message?

Comment: How did you check for triggers? I guess, you just missed it. It has nothing to do with access rights.

Comment: @fancyPanys I checked for triggers with `show triggers`.  As far as I know we do not use triggers in this database.

Answer (score 0):

The current theory is that a conversion script to move us to UTF-8 is currently running and creating tables like _ORIG_new as part of its conversion.  We are going to wait for the conversion script to finish and then rebuild the dev databases and see if the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen if you also try Insert into or Delete statements ?

Insert INTO sometab(somefield1, somefield2) VALUES (a, b).

If that works you should not have problems probably, otherwise you have problems accessing your database.

Second, are you sure you are using the correct database file and that are you connected to it properly. If you are using it in external application (c#), check your connection strings.

Also check how are you executing the query. I cant think of other more specific solution to your problem